# Minimize nested loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code with nested loops. How can I minimize the loop?

`users` result is like:

```
users = [[35, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, nil, 70, 71, 72, 73,
          74, 75, 78, 79, 92, 94, 95, 154, 164, 292, 293, 294, 295, 314],
         [],
         [35],
         [],
         [35, 79, 88],
         [],
         [],
         [36, 35, 56, 78, 87, 95, 65],
         [63, 72, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 87, 90, 93, nil, 96, 111, 157, 159, 160, 271,
          272, 66, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 305, 307, 308, 71, 315],
         [],
         [79, 83, 85, 86, 89, 91, 161, 162, 163, 67, 294, 302, 303, 304, 306,
          309, 310, 311, 312, 313],
         [],
         [314],
         [314],
         []
        ]
```

That's why I need to loop the object in each elements.

And `array` value is:

```
array = [309, 310, 305, 304, 90, 162, 78, 297, 296, 272, 271, 84, 91, 308,
         299, 79, 87, 298, 301, 163, 81, 72, 83, 111, 86, 313, 164, 300, 159,
         315, 160, 307, 82, 69, 312, 89
        ]
```

Thanks!

```
0.upto(users.count).each do |i|
  users[i].each do |user_id|
    if array.include?(user_id)
      puts user_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I have a strong suspicion that you're doing something with these loops that you should be doing with a database query instead.

Comment: Concentrate on clarifying the question. What do you mean by "How can I minimize the loop?" ?.  Show your expected result for the example you gave. Note I've assigned variables to the two arrays. That way readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without defining them.

Comment: Why do you refuse to clarify your question with an edit?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you want to get the common elements from `users` and `array`.

At first make the `users` array `flatten` to make it a single array. Then make it a `uniq` so that one id doesn't repeat again. `compact` will remove the `nil` values. After that make a `&` operation with `array`. And you got your `result`.

```
result = users.flatten.uniq.compact & array
```

Now if you want to print the `result`

```
puts result
```

Comment: I think you meant `&` instead of `&&`. You're returning the value of array that way. & is the intersect method for a Ruby Array.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim, thanks for noticing. yes, `&` is more preferable.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok I also added the print part. Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think that too. The question not cleared. But I think he wants something like this. I'll change it if OP really wants that. Thanks again.

Comment: I deleted my comments because I had misread the OPs code and because the question is not clear. I'll delete this comment also, after you've seen it.

Answer (score 1):

If each sub array of users has no repeated elements, then the following should work

```
users.each { |user| puts array & user }
```